# heif-convert error: JPEG support has not been compiled in

Tags: lib, heif

I'm trying to convert HEIC files to JPEG.
So I installed the libheif library:

- I cloned `https://github.com/strukturag/libheif`
- I ran `./autogen.sh`
- I ran `./configure`
- I ran `make`
- I ran `sudo make install`

Now the `heif-convert` tool is installed but when I run `heif-convert input.HEIC output.jpeg`, I get an error: `JPEG support has not been compiled in`.

I don't understand what I did wrong (or more likely what I forgot to do) and I don't find anything on the internet. Can someone tell me how I can fix this ?

Comment: `configure` usually prints a summary of what was configured at the end of its output. You probably need install the `-dev` package for your jpeg library.

Comment: Anyway, look through the output of configure for any mentions of jpeg, the main problem should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments (thanks btw), the solution was to install libjpeg-dev (via apt) and re-run configure/make/make install.
Works like a charm now.